# multiple alert dialog with list view

Tags: java, android, xml, android-fragments, android-alertdialog

hi i am trying to add a list view to an alert dialog. on click of the ok button on my first alert dialog, the program directs to the response fragment which contains a second dialog box which needs to be populated with the list view. the problem i am having is that i am getting an empty alert box with the list view showing behind it on the fragment

```html
 public class ResponseFragment extends Fragment {
        ListView list;
        private String urlString;
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> oslist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        }
    
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_response, container, false);
            list=(ListView)v.findViewById(R.id.listviewResp);
            urlString = "http://172.20.10.5:1012/easyQ.svc/rest/reasons";
            new getReasons().execute(urlString);
    
    
    
    
            return v;
        }
    
        private class getReasons extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
            protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
                String stream;
                String urlString = strings[0];
                HTTPDataHandler hh = new HTTPDataHandler();
                stream = hh.GetHTTPData(urlString);
                // Return the data from specified url
                System.out.println(stream);
                return stream;
            }
    
            protected void onPostExecute(String stream) {
                if (stream != null)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        JSONObject object = new JSONObject(stream);
                        JSONArray array = object.getJSONArray("reasonsResult");
    
                        for(int i = 0 ; i < array.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject reasonObj = array.getJSONObject(i);
                            String ID = reasonObj.getString("reason_leaving_id");
                            String reason = reasonObj.getString("description");
    
                            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                            map.put("description", reason);
                            map.put("id", ID);
                            oslist.add(map);
                        }
    
                        for(int i = 0; i < oslist.size(); i++)
                        {
    
                            ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(), oslist,
                                    R.layout.dialog_list,
                                    new String[] { "description"}, new int[] {
                                    R.id.txtResp});
    
                            // alertDialog.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_response,null));
                            list.setAdapter(adapter);
                            list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    
                                @Override
                                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                                        int position, long id) {
                                    String branchId = oslist.get(+position).get("id");
                                    final SessionV globalVariable = (SessionV) getActivity().getApplicationContext();
                                    globalVariable.setBranchId(branchId);
                                    Fragment fragment = null;
                                    fragment = new HomeFragment();
                                    getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container_body, fragment).commit();
    
                                }
                            });
                        }
    
                        AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                                getActivity()).create();
                        alertDialog.setTitle("easyQ");
                        alertDialog.setMessage("reason");
                        LayoutInflater inflater = (getActivity()).getLayoutInflater();
                        final View dialogView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_response,null);
                        alertDialog.setView(dialogView);
                        alertDialog.show();
                        alertDialog.show();
    
    
                    }
                    catch(JSONException e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    
    }
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <ListView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/listviewResp"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="15dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
</LinearLayout>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtResp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?listPreferredItemHeightSmall"
        android:checkMark="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorSingle"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="?listPreferredItemPaddingLeft"
        android:paddingRight="?listPreferredItemPaddingRight"
        android:textAppearance="?textAppearanceListItemSmall" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Share the code for `fragment_response` layout. Is that the listview ?

Comment: zahidul i have shared the two xml layouts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to show a `ListView` inside the `AlertDialog` . So, You need to modify some of your code.

**1st :**

You inflate the listview from the `fragment_response` layout. Which is not necessary. In `onCreateView()` method just initialize a new object of `ListView`.

Replace :

```
list=(ListView)v.findViewById(R.id.listviewResp);
```

By

```
list = new ListView(getActivity());
```

**2nd:**

Change this Code :

```
AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(
        getActivity()).create();
alertDialog.setTitle("easyQ");
alertDialog.setMessage("reason");
LayoutInflater inflater = (getActivity()).getLayoutInflater();
final View dialogView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_response,null);
alertDialog.setView(dialogView);
alertDialog.show();
alertDialog.show();
```

By

```
AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity()).create();
alertDialog.setTitle("easyQ");
alertDialog.setMessage("reason");
alertDialog.setView(listView);
alertDialog.show();
```

If other code is ok, then i hope it will work well.